# Tor - chain of connected nodes?

Tags: proxy, tor

For a long time now I have been wondering how to find out where you actually connect to with Tor.

The only thing you can do in Vidalia is show a Network Map of all available Nodes worldwide, which is not related to the nodes you are actually connected to right now.

Comment: Related watching, from Dec 2011: [How governments have tried to block Tor.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX46Qv_b7F4) (There's some PG cursing in the video.)

Answer (score 3):

You are never connected to all nodes, only one. The whole principle of Tor is that only the first node knows where you are. The other ones needn't know.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, but how is it that you can define a (country) specific exit node? Is this the only information that is unencryptedly chained through all nodes?
And how is the number of nodes defined? And what about a session, I guess every node has its own mapping table with Onion addresses?
You don't need to answer these questions in detail, I would be glad if you could link to a web site explaining the concept of it, if you have one. Thanks!

Comment: http://cyberwarzone.com/cyberwarfare/anonymous-networking-how-does-tor-work-explained

Comment: But the client knows all of the nodes it's routing through. So vidalia could show this information.

Comment: Of course, because you need to know the public keys of those nodes

Answer (score 1):

While Vidalia does not provide a way to view your current circuit, other UI's for Tor such as [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en) do. If you don't want to download Arm or another UI for Tor, you can get this information directly from the control port. The following instructions assume you're using a Unix or Unix-like OS:

First you'll want to get the authentication string to use from the auth cookie (this is where it's stored in the TBB, if you've got Tor installed on your system some other way you'll have to use the correct control cookie path):

```
hexdump -e '32/1 "%02x""\n"' Data/Tor/control_auth_cookie
```

Then telnet to the control port (`9151` by default, this may be different on your system):

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9151
AUTHENTICATE $PASSWORD
```

where `$PASSWORD` is the string given by hexdump above.

You can then send: `getinfo circuit-status` which will dump out the circuit info including fingerprints for each hop. Something like this:

```
250+circuit-status=
4 BUILT $9F937131215E4AAE90D685B97AC63938F26A9D5C=alarm,$8587B6C7E22C7DF6F4F79FFD38A0740BF537EFD1=TorAustralisXXVIII,$841C635F57FE77F354DA26AEEB4D12EDF44AF076~Unnamed BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-02-28T23:09:10.107304
3 BUILT $9F937131215E4AAE90D685B97AC63938F26A9D5C=alarm,$1363782D5C2F0345A43076F2EAA9F443B3AD4B76~Unnamed,$EC01CB4766BADC1611678555CE793F2A7EB2D723=sprockets BUILD_FLAGS=IS_INTERNAL,NEED_CAPACITY,NEED_UPTIME PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-02-28T23:09:09.116112
2 BUILT $9F937131215E4AAE90D685B97AC63938F26A9D5C=alarm,$7B4DAFCF17D626828492CE5E587937F57C708681=wtfrelayyoh,$2C289C7F9A303E3A10341368B10A457EC7B2B8D1=Janus0 BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-02-28T23:09:08.123212
1 BUILT $628664B08BD81BB0BF467347F3CE14CB5B915786=Chandler05,$5097CB04C09C0A26E27E86217983C0A374676550=CzechMix,$D64366987CB39F61AD21DBCF8142FA0577B92811=kasperskytor01 BUILD_FLAGS=NEED_CAPACITY PURPOSE=GENERAL TIME_CREATED=2014-02-28T23:09:07.107064
.
250 OK
```

This should work for any version of Tor (TBB or otherwise) which has a control port configured (and on any OS to boot; pretty much everything is going to have telnet or an equivalent). If you've got a control password configured instead of a cookie, skip the hexdump bit and authenticate with that password. If no password is set you can skip the authenticate command.